# Extend list os vectors to a basis

Tags: matrices

Extend

\begin{equation}
{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} }
\end{equation}

To a base of  \begin{equation} M_{22} \end{equation}

I was thinking
\begin{equation}
a \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\        
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
+ b
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\        
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+c
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
w & z
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

But I do not know because I know that there is missing one matrix to get the base, Ido not know if I have to add another matrix before the equal.

Comment: What happens when $x \not = z$?

Comment: Do not feel frightened by the fact that this question was with the vectors as $2\times 2$ matrices.  This should be *no different* than the problem if it were in $\Bbb R^4$ with the vectors being $(1,0,0,1), (0,1,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,1,0)$.  The same process that you would use there would apply here as well.

Comment: "*extend ___ to a basis*"  There are infinitely many correct answers you can give here.  Some are certainly going to be "nicer" looking than others, but that's all it is... looks.  You should know from example that $\Bbb R^4$ is four-dimensional and so you need four basis vectors (*similarly $M_{2\times 2}$ is four-dimensional*).  Pick yourself a fourth vector, any fourth vector, so long as it isn't already in the span of your original three and that will be a good enough answer.

Comment: You can always extend a linearly independent family of vectors (that are matrices in your case) to a basis by adding some vectors from a known basis. Take a basis of $M_{22}$ to apply the result I mentioned to your example. Also notice that the dimension of $M_{22}$ is equal to four. And remember that all basis have the same number of elements... Which is good in order to be able to define the dimension!